# Did Facebook graph just stop working today?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

All of a sudden I'm getting errors when doing requests I've used for years.  For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/dangoodspeed
```

Should return info about my account, but instead it returns the error:

```
(#803) Cannot query users by their username (dangoodspeed)
```

Other sites that use Facebook Graph like [findmyfacebookid.com](http://findmyfacebookid.com) doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what's going on?  Will this be fixed soon?  Will I have to rewrite my apps around these errors?

Comment: I don't think this question is within the scope of stack-exchange. It would make more sense to ask on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It is by design and was announced more than 1 year ago at 4/30/2014

Answer (score 2):

As @WizKid said, this has been announced more than a year ago. You cannot use the `username` anymore, and this is by design:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> - `/me/username` is no longer available.

Comment: So did they just disable graph 1.0 today?  It was working a day or two ago.  Is there no longer a way to get a user's photo from their username now?

Comment: Facebook is gradually upgrading all v1.0 apps since 1st of May 2015. And no, you can't get the photo from a username anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ID of your profile and include it to your Graph path in V2.3
Find the ID using  the Facebook [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me&). 
    /v2.3/me

Include your ID to the Graph path as
 `yourID/feed`